# Android javax.naming.* replacement?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to find an API for my android application that will replace the javax.naming package for DNS look up information.  The java.net.InetAddress gives me some of the information that I need for my DNS tool, but fails to look up the MX and NS records.

Does anyone have a suggestion on the API's I should be using to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick google finds:

http://www.dnsjava.org/

Does what you're looking for.

Comment: I cant believe I missed this when I was searching.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have used [JmDNS](http://jmdns.sourceforge.net/) before with Android successfully.

From their webpage:

"JmDNS is a Java implementation of multi-cast DNS and can be used for service registration and discovery in local area networks."

Would this provide what you are looking for?